# How can I edit "resolved reason" under bugs?

Tags: azure-devops

I need to change the options under "resolve reason" for bugs, yet I don't understand how... would appreciate some help here.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are limitation there and you can't modify reason list for default state. You can add your own state and then you can type anything you want to in `Reason` field but in this case it won't be propagated to `Resolved Reason` in planning:

[image]

To tho this you have to [modify workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-workflow?view=azure-devops), you will also find there confirmation for my above words:

> Unsupported workflow customizations
>
> - You can't modify an inherited state (you can't change its name, color, or category), but you can hide it
> - You can only have one state in the Completed state category. If you add a custom state to the Completed category, any other state is removed or hidden
> - You can't change the name of a custom state
> - You can't specify a Reason for a state, instead, default reasons are defined such as Moved to state Triaged, Moved out of state Triaged
> - You can't change the location of the State and Reason fields on the form